# How to resize videos in wx.media.MediaCtrl

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I need to get different size of videos all being displayed in same size, etc. 600*400px.
I'm using  code I found somewhere, but the problem is that when I open for example  720p video file, video will be shown in its native size.

So is there any possibility to resize video using mediactrl?

If not, what is then the most effiecient way to embed videoplayback in wxpython with resizing option?

I'm running on OSX Lion, MacPython 2.7.2, wxpython 2.8 in 32bit mode

```
import wx
import wx.media
import os


class Panel1(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        #self.log = log
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL|wx.CLIP_CHILDREN)

        # Create some controls
        try:
            self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        except NotImplementedError:
            self.Destroy()
            raise

        loadButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Load File")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onLoadFile, loadButton)

        playButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Play")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPlay, playButton)

        pauseButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Pause")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onPause, pauseButton)

        stopButton = wx.Button(self, -1, "Stop")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onStop, stopButton)

        slider = wx.Slider(self, -1, 0, 0, 0, size=wx.Size(300, -1))
        self.slider = slider
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.onSeek, slider)

        self.st_file = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "Open video file", size=(200,-1))
        self.st_size = wx.StaticText(self, -1, size=(100,-1))
        self.st_len  = wx.StaticText(self, -1, size=(100,-1))
        self.st_pos  = wx.StaticText(self, -1, size=(100,-1))

        # setup the button/label layout using a sizer
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5,5)
        sizer.Add(loadButton, (1,1))
        sizer.Add(playButton, (2,1))
        sizer.Add(pauseButton, (3,1))
        sizer.Add(stopButton, (4,1))
        sizer.Add(self.st_file, (1, 2))
        sizer.Add(self.st_size, (2, 2))
        sizer.Add(self.st_len,  (3, 2))
        sizer.Add(self.st_pos,  (4, 2))
        sizer.Add(self.mc, (5,1), span=(5,1))  # for .avi .mpg video files
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onTimer)
        self.timer.Start(100)

    def onLoadFile(self, evt):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message="Choose a media file",
                            defaultDir=os.getcwd(), defaultFile="",
                            style=wx.OPEN | wx.CHANGE_DIR )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            self.doLoadFile(path)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def doLoadFile(self, path):
        if not self.mc.Load(path):
            wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % path, "ERROR",           wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)
        else:
            folder, filename = os.path.split(path)
            self.st_file.SetLabel('%s' % filename)
            self.mc.SetBestFittingSize()
            self.GetSizer().Layout()
            self.slider.SetRange(0, self.mc.Length())
            self.mc.Play()#ITS TO PROBLEM, WHY IT DOESNT PLAY HERE?#

    def onPlay(self, evt):
        self.mc.Play()

    def onPause(self, evt):
        self.mc.Pause()

    def onStop(self, evt):
        self.mc.Stop()

    def onSeek(self, evt):
        offset = self.slider.GetValue()
        self.mc.Seek(offset)

    def onTimer(self, evt):
        offset = self.mc.Tell()
        self.slider.SetValue(offset)
        self.st_size.SetLabel('size: %s ms' % self.mc.Length())
        self.st_len.SetLabel('( %d seconds )' % (self.mc.Length()/1000))
        self.st_pos.SetLabel('position: %d ms' % offset)



 app = wx.PySimpleApp()
 # create a window/frame, no parent, -1 is default ID
 frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "play audio and video files", size = (600, 350))
 # call the derived class
 Panel1(frame, -1)
 frame.Show(1)
 app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The MediaCtrl has a size parameter in its init. You might try passing that. You can also try the mplayer wrapper. Here's a tutorial on the latter: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/24/wxpython-creating-a-simple-media-player/

Comment: I think the size will restrict the window size; not the video size. I don't think it's possible to resize the video through the MediaCtrl.

Comment: Really? I knew the MediaCtrl was limited, but that sucks!

Answer (score 0):

I think MediaCtrl only sizes them to their native dimensions. You could try to edit them down using some kind of editing software I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import wx
import wx.xrc
import wx.media
import os   

class StaticText(wx.StaticText):
    def SetLabel(self, label):
        if label != self.GetLabel():
            wx.StaticText.SetLabel(self, label)

class Fr_AnaSayfa ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Fapigo Biometrik Sistemi", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 1024,700 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        Bs_AnaSayfa = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        self.Pn_Video = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.Pn_Video.SetMinSize( wx.Size( -1,200 ) )
        Vs_Video = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        self.Pn_Video.SetSizer( Vs_Video )
        self.Pn_Video.Layout()
        Vs_Video.Fit( self.Pn_Video )
        Bs_AnaSayfa.Add( self.Pn_Video, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )
        try:
            backend = ""
            self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl()
            self.mc.ShowPlayerControls(flags=wx.media.MEDIACTRLPLAYERCONTROLS_DEFAULT)
            ok = self.mc.Create(self.Pn_Video, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER,szBackend=backend)
            if not ok:
                raise NotImplementedError
        except NotImplementedError:
            self.Destroy()
            raise




        self.Pn_Button = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( -1,40 ), wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.Pn_Button.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )

        Bs_Button = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        Bs_Button.SetMinSize( wx.Size( -1,40 ) ) 
        self.Bt_Load = wx.Button( self.Pn_Button, wx.ID_ANY, u"Load", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        Bs_Button.Add( self.Bt_Load, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.Bt_Play = wx.Button( self.Pn_Button, wx.ID_ANY, u"Play", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        Bs_Button.Add( self.Bt_Play, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.Bt_Pause = wx.Button( self.Pn_Button, wx.ID_ANY, u"Pause", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        Bs_Button.Add( self.Bt_Pause, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.Bt_Stop = wx.Button( self.Pn_Button, wx.ID_ANY, u"Stop", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        Bs_Button.Add( self.Bt_Stop, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.slider = wx.Slider(self.Pn_Button, -1, 0, 0, 10)
        self.slider.SetMinSize((150, -1))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.OnSeek, self.slider)
        Bs_Button.Add( self.slider, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.OnMediaLoaded)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnLoadFile, self.Bt_Load)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPlay, self.Bt_Play)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPause, self.Bt_Pause)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop, self.Bt_Stop)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.OnSeek, self.slider)


        self.st_size = StaticText(self.Pn_Button, -1, size=(100,-1))
        self.st_len  = StaticText(self.Pn_Button, -1, size=(100,-1))
        self.st_pos  = StaticText(self.Pn_Button, -1, size=(100,-1))


        Bs_Button.Add( self.st_size, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        Bs_Button.Add( self.st_len, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        Bs_Button.Add( self.st_pos, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.Pn_Button.SetSizer( Bs_Button )
        self.Pn_Button.Layout()
        Bs_AnaSayfa.Add( self.Pn_Button, 0, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)
        self.timer.Start(100)


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.ReSize)

        self.SetSizer( Bs_AnaSayfa )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    def OnLoadFile(self, evt):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message="Choose a media file",
                            defaultDir=os.getcwd(), defaultFile="",
                            style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_CHANGE_DIR )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            path = dlg.GetPath()
            self.DoLoadFile(path)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def ReSize(self, evt):
        self.mc.Pause()     
        self.Layout()
        self.mc.SetSize(self.Pn_Video.GetSize())
        self.mc.Play()


    def DoLoadFile(self, path):

        if not self.mc.Load(path):
            wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % path,
                          "ERROR",
                          wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)
            self.Bt_Play.Disable()
        else:
            self.mc.SetInitialSize()

            self.slider.SetRange(0, self.mc.Length())
            self.Bt_Play.Enable()
            self.GetSizer().Layout()

    def OnMediaLoaded(self, evt):
        self.Bt_Play.Enable()

    def OnPlay(self, evt):
        if not self.mc.Play():
            wx.MessageBox("Unable to Play media : Unsupported format?",
                          "ERROR",
                          wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)
        else:
            self.mc.SetInitialSize()
            self.GetSizer().Layout()
            self.slider.SetRange(0, self.mc.Length())

            self.mc.SetSize(self.Pn_Video.GetSize())


    def OnPause(self, evt):
        self.mc.Pause()

    def OnStop(self, evt):
        self.mc.Stop()


    def OnSeek(self, evt):
        offset = self.slider.GetValue()
        self.mc.Seek(offset)

    def OnTimer(self, evt):
        offset = self.mc.Tell()
        self.slider.SetValue(offset)
        self.st_size.SetLabel('size: %s' % self.mc.GetBestSize())
        self.st_len.SetLabel('length: %d seconds' % (self.mc.Length()/1000))
        self.st_pos.SetLabel('position: %d' % offset)

    def ShutdownDemo(self):
        self.timer.Stop()
        del self.timer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Fapigo = wx.App()
    Fr_AnaSayfa = Fr_AnaSayfa(None)
    Fapigo.SetTopWindow(Fr_AnaSayfa)
    Fr_AnaSayfa.Show()
    Fapigo.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Do not only include code into the answer but also add some explanations as well.